# Next js dynamic routes work as expected in development but returns 404 page in production

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, nextjs-dynamic-routing

I am trying to use dynamic routes to render pages using next js. When user hits the url (http://localhost:3000/post/123) it should render a page and I should be able to pull the id from the url using useRouter() hook and display it in the page as shown below. This works perfectly fine in local dev but when I host this on firebase, the url returns 404 page. I am confused what's wrong. Please help.

```
// [post].tsx
import React from 'react'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

const Details = () => {
    
    const { query } = useRouter()
    const postID = query.post

    return (
        <div>Post id: {postID}</div>
    )
}

export default Details
```

package.json:
[image: package.json:]

Folder structure:
[image: Folder structure:]

Answer (score 0):

For the `URL` `http://localhost:3000/post/123` the `router.query` object would look like this

```
//[post].jsx/tsx
{ "post": "123" }
```

> What you name inside the `[ ]` in your case, `post` would be the variable name returned by the `router`

It takes some time to hydrate so I would recommend you to use `useEffect` to capture the id.

```
const router = useRouter()
const {post} = router.query

useEffect(()=>{
  if(!post) return
  //get from firebase
},[router])
```

[`NEXT JS Dynamic Routing Documentation`](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes)

Comment: I read the documentation and I am already doing what you suggested, as you can see from my code. It is working fine locally, but when I host the code on firebase, the url(https://test-project-b1912.web.app/post/123) returns 404. I used this code in a previous project last year successfully and its still working fine.

Comment: If it's working locally, try using firebase logs to debug the problem in live environment. I'll look more into this if anyone's having the same issue. If you found something please let us know

Comment: Not sure about what firebase logs you are referring to but I deployed it on vercel and didn't see the issue. Looks the issue is in fact with firebase.

Comment: sorry I got confused with another question. First set up a [`Vercel Log Drain`](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/observability/log-drains-overview/log-drains). Or send me the GitHub repo I'll try something out